# Automatic logout after inactivity Drupal 8

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, drupal-8

I'm creating a new site in Drupal 8 where users can login. For security reasons I would like to create a custom module that closes the inactive 3 minutes user session. I've already tried to use the Automatic Logout module, but it's not for me, becouse i have a custom login. Does anyone have an idea of how it can be created?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to make with JavaScript:

```
<script>
 setTimeout(function(){                                 // set a timeout-event
  window.location.href = "http://example.com/logout/";  // make a redirect to the logout page
 }, 180000);                                            // set timeout to 3 minutes ( 1000 * 60 * 3 )
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I would like to close the session after 3 minutes of user inactivity, not every 3 minutes.

Comment: this is not an interval. this is a timeout. everytime the user changes the page, it starts from new.

Comment: Yes it work, but i can't work in the page for more than 3 minutes. It is too limiting.

Comment: then you could connect it for example with the mousemovement or reset the timeout when the user makes clicks, keyups or something else.

Comment: Ok, perfect, you put me on the right track. Thank you.

Comment: This is a bad idea. If a user logs in and closes the page within 3 minutes he will stay logged in and possibly never log out (depending on the Drupal settings).